# Is it possible to pass a workingdirectory with a space to MSBuild EXEC command task?

Tags: msbuild, exec, space, working-directory

For the `Command` parameter, one can escape the path via `&quot;`, however, this doesn't work if there is a space in the `WorkingDirectory` parameter.

Does anyone have a solution?

Perhaps changing my environment `HOMEDRIVE`\ `HOMEPATH` setting before calling the build task, but that's horrible and probably not trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to escape anything or do anything special. This should work:

```
<Exec Command="Path_to_some_executable.exe" WorkingDirectory="Path to some directory\with spaces" />
```

Comment: Note I tested this with MSbuild 4.0